# Why is Python 3 looking in my Python 2.7 package directory for packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.5

OS (Linux): [Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr)

For some reason, my Python 3.5.2 is looking into the Python 2.7 packages directory instead of its own:

```
] python3 -m ensurepip

Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
    setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
    pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

More details:

```
] python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 29 2016, 09:41:38)
[GCC 6.1.1 20160511] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
>>>
```

^^^-- That seems correct and does not mention anything about the 2.7 packages directory.

It looks like it should only be looking in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`, but for some reason, it is also looking in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` where it has no business in looking.

For example, look at what happens when I try to install `psycopg2` as a Python 3 module:

```
] python3 -m pip install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
    psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

It is finding it as an installed package in the 2.7 distribution and failing to install its Python 3 version in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`.

To add even more confusion into the mix, I try going straight for [pip 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)), but to no avail:

```
] pip3 install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
    psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

] cat `which pip3`
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

**Update**: `PYTHONPATH` was set to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. This was the cause of the issue above. Credit goes to user *be_good_do_good* for helping me figure out which *screw to turn* to get things to work as they should.

Comment: Can you post your PATH value and PYTHONPATH value

Comment: @be_good_do_good was thinking about the same, maybe there is a manually added 2.7 site-packages in the path

Comment: You should also post the value of `sys.path`. You also might have a `.pth` file in one of the searched locations as well. `sys.path` should illuminate that. It might also be worth running in verbose mode (`python -v`) to see where modules are being imported from.

Comment: That's the weirdest prompt I've seen: `]`. I keep looking for the matching `[`.

Comment: @be_good_do_good, kudos to you: `PYTHONPATH` was set to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Feel free to post your comment as an answer for proper accepted answer credit..

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn posted as answer, thank you!! :)

Comment: How to you solve this? Did you simply remove the path from `PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PYTHONPATH might have been set to 2.7 distribution packages, which might be causing this.