# why is python3 code calling python2 modules?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

i have docker image with ubuntu 18.04 where i'm attempting to get jupyter installed.

```
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade \
      tornado \
      jupyterlab \
      jupyterhub

RUN   /usr/bin/python3 `which jupyter` lab clean && \
      /usr/bin/python3 `which jupyter` lab build
```

however, upon building the image, i'm getting the following error:

```
Step 4/13 : RUN   /usr/bin/python3 `which jupyter` lab clean &&       jupyter lab build
 ---> Running in b4a988612018
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-lab", line 7, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab_server/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab_server/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .server import ServerApp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab_server/server.py", line 14, in <module>
    from notebook.base.handlers import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 605, in <module>
    from .extensions import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/extensions.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tornado.log import LogFormatter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/log.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado.escape import _unicode
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tornado.util import unicode_type
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/util.py", line 18, in <module>
    import typing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/typing.py", line 782, in <module>
    AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', bytes, unicode)
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

why is python3 attempting to use the python3 modules? how can i get rid fo this error?

Comment: This could be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661908/why-is-python-3-looking-in-my-python-2-7-package-directory-for-packages